# GitLab CI/CD для новичка Qt проекта с++

Tags: qt, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Я пробовала найти инфу в интернете, но толком объяснений нет. Можно ли подробный гайд с пояснением как с нуля новичку запустить через CI хотя бы проверку компиляции проекта QT.

Нашла определения докера, контейнера и раннера. Немного не поняла: докер ставится один раз, а что и как обстоят дела с контейнером и раннером. Плаваю в понимании что есть что и зачем.

•   Как ставить это всё и подключать? На работе нет интернета, но есть локальный сервер. Также сказали, если надо определенный сервер с ОС, то его поставят.

Нужно ли определенный докер ставить? что делать с контейнером (или раннером?). Его нужно как-то настраивать? Нужно ли делать контейнер в контейнере и тд? Как, зачем и тп?
Нужно ли в контейнер или раннер положить что-то или настроить, чтобы потом работать…
Нужно ли скачать несколько образов ОС заранее или потом в `.yml` писать с какой ОС работать…

•   Проект - консольное приложение на QT c++. Desktop_Qt_5_9_2_MinGW_32bit
qmake
Проверять проект на windows (7, 10, 11), линукс.

•   Далее, как в yml написать проверку на сборку проекта? Смотрела видео на ютубе там было интересное с GitHub там логика, что о проекте информации нет и нужно команды прописать: скачать на сервер, а потом только работать... После сборки нужно ли сохранить артефакты, для следующих заданий (позже нужно разобраться как писать тесты).
Мне хотелось бы сделать job, который собирает проект .pro
Возможно, c параллельной компиляции Qt: Настройки сборки-Этапы сборки-параметры make: `-j8`

```
stages:
  - build

simplebuild:
  stage: build
  script:
    -  ???
   // Нужно ли говорить на какой ОС собирать?
   // Есть способ указать на многопоточную сборку?
```

•   Есть ли гайды с командами CI в GitLab. Кажется на GitHub из видео есть страница, где можно искать пользовательские готовые команды и указать, что используем ту команду, а дальше писать шаги.

Comment: *"подробный гайд с пояснением как с нуля новичку..."* - Допущение, что хотя бы вводное слово к подобному гайду по организации CI при кросс-платформенной разработке на С++ может поместиться в ответ на этом сайте - невероятный оптимизм. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RHln.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходя из довольно сумбурных вопросов без конкретики, следует для себя понять, что искать и в какой последовательности делать. Примеры, мануалы и ссылки, разумеется, есть, но исключительно для понимания и обучения, потому как конкретное техническое задание отсутствует в стартовом вопросе. Итак:

1. Нужно понять, каким образом оркестрируются docker контейнеры в вашей
   компании/окружении (используются ли они и хотят ли их видеть в
   будущем вообще):

   - обычный runner внутри docker ([Docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html)), который [создан](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html) без технологий [оркестрации контейнеров](https://habr.com/ru/companies/kts/articles/591355/). В принципе,
     это стартовый набор, так как можно создавать GitLab CI runners как
     для запуска внутри контейнера средствами самого GitLab runner'а, так и просто обычный runner в системе, [выставив необходимое количество
     параллельных выполнений](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828805/configure-runner-to-run-multiple-jobs-at-the-same-time) (обратите внимание, что при параллельном запуске в одной системе ничто не должно использовать одни и те же файловые пути и устанавливать одни и те же зависимости - все должно
     выполняться в пределах workspace, или директории с проектом внутри
     текущего запуска).
   - [Kubernetes executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html). Интеграция GitLab CI с [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/ru/) так же [довольно хорошо описана](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/ci_cd_workflow.html).

     **Но я бы на начальной стадии рекомендовал пока что воздержаться от
     оркестраторов, так как это дополнительное обслуживание и
     дополнительные знания. Так же дела обстоят и с контейнерами (docker, или
     lxc).** Начните
     с одного запуска без параллелей: ничего страшного, если пару недель-месяцев
     задания на этих GitLab executor'ах будут стоять некоторое время в
     очереди. После того, как все отладите в рамках одного или нескольких
     запусков на одной системе, приступите к переносу в docker. Но обратите
     внимание, что после установки (если таковая будет) пакета при
     тестировании, следующий запуск должен корректно этот пакет удалить и, в
     этом случае, параллельные запуски с установкой крайне нежелательны.
     Docker image, как контейнеризированная система, с отделенным userspace,
     имеет свои особенности и нюансы, связанные с администрированием, а это
     дополнительные знания и время при собирании image, установки зависимостей
     и т.д.

     Далее потребуется понимание работы с [git workflow](https://habr.com/ru/articles/60030/)
     ([официальная страница GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/topics/version-control/what-is-git-workflow/)), потому как вам придется понимать в каких случаях ваши [pipeline'ы триггерятся](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/07/12/guide-to-ci-cd-pipelines/). *"Что в какую ветку сливается"*, *"почему и для чего ветка называется feature_xxxx, или bug_xxxx"* - вот ваши вопросы на этом этапе (разумеется, если в вашей компании номер `xxxx` отражает задачу в таск-трекере).

     Не будет лишним так же знать про переменные окружения (envorinment variables) и [встроенные](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/cicd_variables.html) в pipeline [переменные](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) (некоторые из них вы будете использовать довольно часто).       Так же уделите внимание тэгам (если разработчики используют) и commit messages: вполне возможно, комит на с сообщением `WIP`, или `wip` запускать CI (или его отдельную часть: например, тестирование после сборки) не нужно. Таким образом в вашем `gitlab-ci.yml` могут появиться примерно следующие строчки:

     ```
     rules:
       - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE !~ /^(?i)WIP(.?)*/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
         when: never
     ```

     Теги находятся в переменной `CI_COMMIT_TAG`, а commit без тега будет иметь условие: `$CI_COMMIT_TAG == null`.

     Так же пригодятся навыки администрирования операционных систем: Windows, а если еще нужно собрать и тестировать - Linux. Возьмите самый простой дистрибутив Linux, если еще в вашей компании не появился какой-либо стандарт: Ubuntu вполне подойдет, так как по этому дистриубутиву есть отдельное комьюнити для обмена опытом [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/) и есть вполне исчерпывающая [русскоязычная документация](https://ubuntu.ru/doku.php).

     Вам предстоит детально понять структуру [GitLab CI/CD pipeline'ов](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/), а точнее [структуру файла](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/) [**.gitlab-ci.yml**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/gitlab_ci_yaml.html): workflow, stages, jobs, variables, extends, tags и т.д. Попутно, сможете найти множество [.gitlab-ci.yml examples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/) - они [есть и в рунете](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%20gitlab%20ci%20pipeline&t=canonical&ia=web).

     Параллельно, при написании pipeline, столкнетесь с особенностями синтаксиса [YAML](https://yaml.org/), особенно, когда дойдете до мультистроковых строчных значений ([yaml multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-in-yaml-over-multiple-lines#21699210)). В целом, YAML довольно прост и под него есть инструменты проверки синтаксиса: [yamllint](https://www.yamllint.com/) ([доступен к установке](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint) через [python pip](https://pypi.org/project/yamllint/), а следовательно и запуска локально и в CI/CD), а так же [prettier](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=install%20prettier&t=canonical&ia=web), который имеет [встроенную функцию автоформатирования](https://prettier.io/blog/2018/07/29/1.14.0.html). Но в первую очередь: в самом web-интерфейсе GitLab есть проверка [синтаксиса yaml-файлов](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/lint.html) - при внимательном изучении информации о CI/CD pipeline'ов вы столкнетесь с ним при попытка запуска CI/CD из неправильного yaml-файла. Обычно ссылка в браузере имеет вид:

     ```
     http(s)://gitlab.domain/gitlab_group/gitlab_project/-/ci/lint
     ```

     На начальной стадии избегайте сложных по структуре pipeline'ов (Keep it simple): начните с одного стейджа (stage) и джобы (job) (например, сборки) и приступайте к следующему стейджу только после того, как отладите этот. Со временем, ваш CI-CD к проекту и без того обрастет workflow, условиями, проверками и переменными. Extend'ы и include'ы для переиспользования кода и джоб оставьте на потом.

     **ВНИМАНИЕ!** Прежде, чем вы приступите к созданию своего pipeline, внимательно изучите уже имеющиеся в GitLab шаблоны проектов: вероятно, уже есть подходящий шаблон. Для этого создайте пустой проект и выберете наиболее подходящий шаблон.
2. Проверка на собираемость пакета называется "build test", или, не исключено, что "sanity test". В вашем случае -- это qmake, а значит ["qmake in gitlab ci examples"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065342/using-gitlab-ci-for-qt-projects), или просто ["qmake manual"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-manual.html) ([русскоязычный мануал](http://www.doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.5.0/qmake-manual.html)). В принципе, далее Qt можно собирать внутри docker:

   - [Compiling Qt with Docker multi-stage and multi-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040020/gui-qt-application-in-a-docker-container), включая [пример на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040020/gui-qt-application-in-a-docker-container).

     Единственное, что здесь остается неуточненным -- это, что включает в себя ваш Qt проект и его взаимодейтсвие с пользователем, поскольку docker images по умолчанию не имеют своего собственного графического адаптера. Поэтому после сборки дальнейшее тестирование, когда дойдете, может потребовать установки на инстанс с графическим адаптером (например, виртуальные машины - систем виртуализации и гипервизоров множество), но так же возможен "проброс" видеокарты в контейнер ([docker GPU path-through](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=docker%20gpu%20passthrough&t=canonical&ia=web)).

   Таким образом ваш `gitlab-ci.yml` без docker будет иметь примерный вид:

   ```
   stages:
     - build

   build_windows:
     stage: build
     tags:
       - windows
       - builder
     script:
       - <windows build command(s)>

   build_linux:
     stage: build
     tags:
       - linux
       - builder
     script:
       - <linux build command(s)>
   ```

   где команды (script) для сборки можно [посмотреть в официальной документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/build-sources.html), как под Windows, так и под Linux.

   Сборка в docker будет отличаться лишь блоком:

   ```
   image: "registry.example.com/my/image:latest"
   ```

   что описано в [GitLab CI документации](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html). Для [Ubuntu 20.04, взятой с dockerhub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63833973/how-to-specify-image-platform-in-gitlab-ci-yml): `image: ubuntu:20.04` ([ссылка](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/) на ubuntu image на dockerhub). Очень вероятно, что для docker image так же будет необходимо установить дополнительные зависимости, воспользовавшись `before_script`:

   ```
   build_linux:
     stage: build
     tags:
       - linux
       - builder
     before_script:
       - apt updage && apt upgrade && apt install <package_1> <package_2> -y
     script:
       - <linux build command(s)>
   ```

   *(Ввиду своей приверженности к Unix и по некоторым другим соображениям я не желаю иметь опыт работы с docker на ОС Windows, поэтому тему "Включить подсистему Linux" оставляю профильным специалистам :) Однако, русскоязычных мануалов на этот счет более, чем достаточно).*

   Разумеется, [Qt уже использовали внутри docker](https://forum.qt.io/topic/92462/docker-image-for-qt), поэтому можно  поискать [готовые docker files](https://github.com/qtdocker), или [docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/vookimedlo/ubuntu-qt/tags/), добавив свои  специфичные зависимости.
3. `make -j8` означает собирать в 8 потоков, значение которых обычно делают равным количеству потоков (CPU threads) в системе. В обычном Linux дистрибутиве их количество в системе можно посмотреть командой:

   ```
   cat /proc/cpuinfo
   ```

   тогда как в самом docker изнутри (без использования различных трюков с LXCFS) этой командой посмотреть не удастся, но, тем не менее, ограничивать количество ресурсов для docker контейнера [возможно](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/).

   - [Building Common Project Types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-common-projects.html).
4. [GitLab CI](https://about.gitlab.com/solutions/continuous-integration/) и [Github workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows) -- это не одно и то же: они имеют несколько разные синтаксис и структуру, хоть и тех же YAML-файлов. Но, да, Github имеет [русскоязычную документацию](https://docs.github.com/ru/actions/using-workflows). **Без знания английского будет сложно**, поскольку те же yaml файлы имеют типично английские инструкции и токены, они более-менее стандартны и понятны при наличиии достаточного технического бэкграунда.
5. По мере написания jobs вам придется хотя бы поверхностно вникнуть в bash scripting для Linux и bat для Windows: циклы, условия и простейшие конструкции, такие как `sed`, `grep` могут облегчить жизнь. В bat для Windows своя "кухня", хоть и похожая.
6. Настроить рабочее окружение так же не будет лишним. Если вы предполагаете заниматься, или соприкасаться с Linux-системами, то идеальным вариантом будет [Ubuntu desktop](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) в качестве настольной системы и [remmina](https://remmina.org/) для подключения к RDP в Windows. Редактировать yaml-файлы лучше в нормальных IDE: [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/), или любая IDE от JetBrains (например, [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)) -- тут дело вкуса. Для них есть встроенные плагины и подсветка синтаксиса для того же YAML и они обе есть в Ubuntu Software (snap).

   Поскольку Linux система предполагает довольно частое использование консоли, то однозначно рекомендую использование [tmux](https://tmuxcheatsheet.com/), zsh и фреймворка [ohmyzsh](https://ohmyz.sh/). *Выбор самого эмулятора терминальной сессии оставляю "за кадром" (поскольку это "вкусовщина"), но `apt install terminator` -- тоже вполне достойный выбор.*
7. С, а в особенности C++ -- это весьма непростой для новичка низкоуровневый язык программирования, как таковой. В процессе сборки могут всплыть нетривиальные для начального уровня вопросы. Знание азов программирования, не говоря уже о самой "низкоуровневой кухне" и знаний Qt, - могут существенно ускорить процесс вместо гугления и дергания коллег с вопросом: "почему твое ИКС не собирается" :)
8. **Артефакты после сборки** *(я специально выделил этот пункт последним, так как на данном этапе это далеко не самое главное)*.

   На самом деле docker образ со всем установленным [можно "сохранить в" и "экспортировать из" tar архива](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142450/how-to-export-my-local-docker-image-to-a-tar-and-the-load-on-another-computer), а далее положить на тот же внутренний ftp, если, например кому-то захочется протестировать вручную. Это самый простой способ.

   Более сложный заключается в хранении на локальном [docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/), поскольку каждый запуск job'ы в GitLab CI будет пересоздавать и пересобирать образ docker заново (это нативно, у оркестраторов есть еще и свои нюансы). Даже на компиляцию заново будет уходить время. Поэтому к этому моменту лучше позаботиться о хранении собранных docker images.

   Можно передавать между stages через артефакты: тогда придется каждый раз все равно пересобирать, или парсить линк на артефакт и скачивать. Однако использование локального docker registry будет более удобным, хоть это и и дополнительная "сущность", которую нужно поддерживать.

## PS:

Весь ваш дальнеший рабочий процесс разработки CI/CD будет вертеться вокруг указанных тем, любопытства и улучшения уже существующего, таким образом, вытесняя всю первоначальную "копипасту примеров", пока вы учились и "игрались", пониманием и более отлаженными конвейерами. Это довольно долгий путь и невозможно объяснить все детально в одном ответе здесь, но начальные примеры и ссылки, а так же информация "с чего начать" даны.